# Is there a way to prevent access of buffer read/write of usb mass storage device, while still being able to mount it?

Tags: windows, permissions, active-directory, usb, usb-mass-storage

The company I work for produces an external device, that can be connected to a Windows PC via USB. Most of it's features the PC software accesses using file operations on the mass storage drive the device exposes on connection. Some advanced features use USB buffer read and buffer write functions.

Now I have a tiny amount of customers which have no problems using the mass storage features, but are not able to use the buffer features. Since both of them are in big companies I would assume, that is has something to do with Active Directory rules/permissions, but I struggle to find out which rule it might be.

Any ideas?